# Twiiter4j: Finding User's Country

Tags: java, twitter, web-crawler, twitter4j

I am making an App to return all the users specific to certain location. I am using getFollowersList to get followers of some celebrities(e.g. US) and then get location of that follower using user.getStatus().getPlace().getCountry(). But it does not seem to work. Any suggestions why this is happening? everytime it returns null.
here's the code:

```
BufferedWriter red = null;
try {
                    red = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter ("newcode.txt"));
                    }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
ArrayList<User> followers = new ArrayList<User>();
           PagableResponseList<User> usersResponse = null;
long cursor = -1;

 do {
                try { 
                    if (0 < args.length) {
                        usersResponse = twitter.getFollowersList(args[0], cursor, 150);
                        System.out.println("size() of first iteration:" + usersResponse.size());
                        followers.addAll(usersResponse);
                        cursor = usersResponse.getNextCursor();
                        counter++;
                        } 
                        else {
                            System.out.println("enter any argument");
                        }           

                    } 
                catch (TwitterException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
} while ((cursor) != 0);

            for ( User user : followers) {
                try {
                    red.write("Location> ");
                    red.write(user.getLocation());
                    red.write("\t");
                    red.write("Status location> ");
                    red.write(user.getStatus().getPlace().getCountry());
                    red.write("\t");
                } catch(NullPointerException e) {
                    red.write("null found");
                    red.write("\t");
                }
catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                red.newLine();
            }
```

Comment: If user doesn't share location details, you will get null.

Comment: ya..i also saw that afterwards, the location field is custom.